# Visual Studio with Xamarin SDK license agreement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, mobile

Right now I hate Visual Studio.

I install Visual Studio 2019, install Xamarin on it. Create a blank project. A window pops up asking me to accept the SDK license agreement; I do. VS status bar stuck at "Waiting for license agreement".

Fine, I'll wait. 45 min later, nothing changes. I go manually through an elevated CMD and run `sdkmanager.bat --licenses` and accept all of them. Restart Visual Studio. Waiting for license agreement. Try to open SDK Manager, "there was an error trying to load, please retry". Try to open up the Android Device Manager... "Android device manager has stopped working"; sure, I'll bite and debug, maybe I forgot to install something. Yeah, "ArgumentException, oldValue cannot be length 0."

Wait what?... Okay, I'll manually install the Android SDK; I do so, I change my route in VS. "This project requires an SDK".

Okay, f*** it, maybe Visual Studio 2019 ain't working yet with Xamarin. Installed VS 2017; fire it up, create a project, all fine and dandy, "We're installing an SDK, this may take a few minutes. For more info check the output in the console window."

One hour later, there is no progress bar, there is NO CONSOLE WINDOW anymore in Visual Studio (thanks Microsoft!) and the output window has no output (how ironic).

I'm out of ideas. Frustrated as ****. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

About **[Setting up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows)** , you can follow this to start the SDK Manager in Visual Studio, click **Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager**:

[image]

When selecting platform sdk to install or update , a dialog may be shown with the message, *The following package requires that you accept its license terms before installing*:

[image]

If the process not continuing after a while , you need to check the network whehter supports the SDK updated . **Sometimes** ,the gateway of network or firewall will afftet this .

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are running Visual Studio with admin privileges

I encountered this error right now and it solved itself by running the application without any admin privileges

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34524393)